# Can I change data with a std::shared_lock on a std::shared_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, memory-barriers

I have multiple buffers being shared with multiple reader/writer threads, and different writers change the data as different manners.

For example, Writer1 merely appends new data, while Writer2 extends the size of buffer(re-alloc memory and move data).

If I put a single mutex to sync all the accesses to the data, the performance maybe not better, because most reader just need to read a single buffer, and most writer just need to write a little piece of data to a single buffer.

If I prepare one mutex for each buffer, the locking/unlocking relationship between threads will be more complicated.

Now I want to confirm a thing:

**If a writer change the data only with a shared_lock on the mutex, whether the others would see dirty data with a unique_lock/shared_lock on same mutex?**

I coded an experimental program as following, and it looks like no error, but I still dare not use it in product.

```
atomic_bool    g_abShouldRun = true;
sem_t          g_semDoIt1;
sem_t          g_semDone1;
sem_t          g_semDoIt2;
sem_t          g_semDone2;
shared_mutex   g_mutex;
int g_iX = 3, g_iY = 9, g_iR1 = 1, g_iR2 = 3;

void writer() {
   std::srand( 8 );

   while( g_abShouldRun ) {
      sem_wait( &g_semDoIt1 );
      while( rand() % 8 != 0 )
         ;

      {
         shared_lock<shared_mutex> lk( g_mutex );
         g_iX *= 2;
         g_iY *= 2;
      }
      sem_post( &g_semDone1 );
   };
};

void reader() {
   std::srand( 8 );

   while( g_abShouldRun ) {
      sem_wait( &g_semDoIt2 );
      while( rand() % 8 != 0 )
         ;

      {
         unique_lock<shared_mutex> lk( g_mutex );
         g_iR1 = g_iX;
         g_iR2 = g_iY;
      }
      sem_post( &g_semDone2 );
   };
};

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   int iLasting = 10, iError = 0;
   if( argc > 1 )
      iLasting = atoi( argv[1] );
   steady_clock::time_point tpEnd = steady_clock::now() + seconds( iLasting );

   if( sem_init( &g_semDoIt1, 0, 0 ) || sem_init( &g_semDone2, 0, 0 ) ||
         sem_init( &g_semDoIt2, 0, 0 ) || sem_init( &g_semDone2, 0, 0 ) ) {
      cerr << "Failed to create semaphors." << endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   thread thd1( writer );
   thread thd2( reader );

   while( steady_clock::now() < tpEnd ) {
      sem_post( &g_semDoIt1 );
      sem_post( &g_semDoIt2 );
      sem_wait( &g_semDone1 );
      sem_wait( &g_semDone2 );
      if( g_iR1 * 3 != g_iR2 )
         ++iError;
   }
   g_abShouldRun = false;
   sem_post( &g_semDoIt1 );
   sem_post( &g_semDoIt2 );
   thd1.join();
   thd2.join();
   sem_destroy( &g_semDoIt1 );
   sem_destroy( &g_semDoIt2 );
   sem_destroy( &g_semDone1 );
   sem_destroy( &g_semDone2 );
   cout << "Error:" << iError << endl;
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following problems jump out at a quick look:

1. change the code to use `unique_lock` when *writing*;
2. change the code to use `shared_lock` when *reading*;
3. do not modify other common global variables when *reading* -- that will practically be writing, just in a different place;
4. how many { `shared_mutex`s, function using `unique_lock`, function using `shared_lock` } tuples you'll be using with multiple threads and multiple buffers, you'll need to figure out yourself -- but it'll be between 1 and the number of buffers.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  But I don't intend to fix the sample codes, I need to confirm my thought.

Comment: I don't really know what your thought is. You are using `shared_lock` when writing and `unique_lock` when reading. That is conceptually wrong, but in that particular case when using *a single writer* it will still work. When using multiple writers it will definitely fail.

Comment: Yes, I know there can be only one writer writing at same time.  In fact there is another mutex will ensure only one writer pass through at same time before it locking this shared_mutex.  Because the logic of my product code is too complicated, so I just show a sample program.